Existing 30 amp breaker to subpanel best way to utilize max power
I removed an 120 year old barn which had a 30amp breaker supplying a 2 pole subpanel in that barn. Built a new pole barn, do not want to dig new wire because of cost. I am 70 and will not be expanding in my lifetime.
Bought a bigger panel but need to know best way to get as much power as possible from the 30 amps. Still just 2 20 amps breakers or too much? . I know 1 20 amp would supply for lights the other receptacles. Which should I connect garage door openers to lights or receptacles.
Supply requirements are 2 garage door openers, 6-8 100 watt LED Low Bay round lights, receptacles not sure how many. Types of equipment running from this load would be a Chop saw, small compressor, sanders. Small shop stuff. Any other suggestions without trenching new wire?

If it's a two-pole (240V) 30A breaker you can use 7200W intermittently, or 5760W continuously.
Given that typical loads are not maximum, and maximum loads on all breakers is unusual at the same time, you could run 4x15A breakers (at 120V each) to the max with a 30A 240V feed, but very likely you could run 2x20A and 2x15A without issue, depending on the loads being served.
The compressor is likely the worst load. For that, it might be worth putting in a suitable 10/15A 240V breaker at the sub-panel if it can be rewired to run on 240V.
Lights could certainly be hung off a 15A circuit, and then they would not go dark unless you managed to overload the feed breaker.
You're unlikely to run both garage door openers and any of your 120V tools at the same time, so they could share a circuit.

Unfortunately it is a 120v 30 amp

Most breakers are never used to their full amps/derated amps. A 20 amp breaker with the 80% use is 1920w.
The lights would be ~half of this, if on. Most small shop tools are just a bit more.
30 amps should be plenty since only the lights will be on full when using a shop tool or an opener, unless you have a party in there.
Older sub panels sometimes had neutral and ground bonded together, which has changed to requiring the newer ones to have ground and neutral separate, and to have ground rods for detached buildings.

Watts depend on voltage.
